# Are arbitrary coproducts filtered colimits?

Tags: category-theory

A coproduct in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a colimit over a diagram $F:S\to\mathcal{C}$, where $S$ is a *set*. So my question is equivalent to asking whether a set is a *filtered* category.

The nLab says that a filtered category is a category in which every finite diagram has a cocone. I am not sure if I can say whether a set, when considered as a category, has this property. I would be grateful if someone could help me clarify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a coproduct is not a filtered colimit in general, because your set $S$ is interpreted as a *discrete* category, and a discrete category is not filtered if it has at least two objects : take $x,y$ two different objects. If the category was filtered you would have some $z$ with morphism $x\to z$ and $y\to z$, but that's impossible because that implies $z=x$ and $z=y$.

<strike>This being said, coproducts are filtered colimits if your category has an initial element : indeed, if $O$ is an initial object in $\mathcal{C}$, and if $(A_i)_{i\in S}$ is a family of objects in $\mathcal{C}$, then the coproduct of the $A_i$ is the colimit of the diagram given by the canonical maps $O\to A_i$, and this gives a diagram over a filtered category : the discrete category for $S$ plus an additional point (corresponding to $O$) with a unique morphism to each point of $S$.</strike>

EDIT: This was a confusion as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: A category is filtered if every finite diagram has a **cocone**, not a cone. Your first paragraph is right up to inversing the direction of the arrow, your second one however is not: as a matter of fact, filtered colimits are exactly those colimits commuting with finite limits in $\mathsf{Set}$, amd I'm pretty confident one can show that coproducts does not commute with some equalizers for example.

Comment: You're right, I confused filtered and cofiltered colimits.